# Generic HID USB keeps trying to install in Win10 Bootcamp

Tags: windows-10, boot-camp, usb-hid

I have a Generic USB HID device (a USB weight scale). When I plug it into a MacMini with Bootcamp Win10 configuration, the USB keeps trying to install again and again (you can hear the windows sounds). The weird part is that if I run the software that reads the device, it works just fine. And the device stops installing as long as I have the software running. as soon as I stop it, the device begins to install again.

All other USB devices install just fine on the same computer.

And the same device in a different machine (win7) installs just fine.

Any help?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the chime only is played, when a USB device is detected.  This means the device is going undetected.  Have you tried a different USB port?  How about a different USB cable?

Comment: Tried all USB ports. And actually this computer used to be running on mac osx + Parrallels and the device worked just fine. Bootcamp should in theory be a direct connection.